# Remove MariaDB in non-interactive mode

Tags: apt, mariadb, uninstall

When I want to remove MariaDB from the system, I run `# apt remove --purge mariadb*`, but then I get a prompt like this one:

[image: MariaDB uninstall prompt]

Is there a way for me to skip this prompt specifying a value for yes or no? I tried `# yes | apt remove --purge mariadb*`, but it just managed to freeze the installer.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best that I can think is this:

```
 DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt remove --purge -yq mariadb\*
 rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

WARNING: This could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `debconf` preseeding to answer the question; in your case, as far as I can tell this would be something like

```
echo mariadb-galera-server-5.5 mysql-server-5.1/postrm_remove_databases boolean true | debconf-set-selections
```

To determine the exact values to use for the first two parts (“`mariadb-galera-server-5.5`” and “`mysql-server-5.1/postrm_remove_databases`”), you need to determine which package is prompting you (look at the title of the window in your screenshot), and look at the template value it expects (in its `postrm`, `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-galera-server-5.5.postrm`). You can also look at the output of `debconf-get-selections` and look for the relevant entry.

Then run `apt` with `debconf` in non-interactive mode:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt purge mariadb\*
```